# Legend from Multiple Data Frames

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, arcgis-10.4, data-frame

I have a map containing multiple data frames, the continental US, Alaska, Hawaii, PR, and Guam.

These data frames contain different symbology which I would like displayed in a legend.

Currently, the legend only shows the symbology from the active data frame, continental US in this instance.

Is there anyway to combine data frames so the legend displays the symbols from all data frames while maintaining the extent of the continental US?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way that I've found to achieve this is to create an extra data frame, which is not visible on your finished map, but which contains all layers which are to be represented in your legend with the appropriate symbology for the given areas. You will remove any of the legends from your other data frames from the finished map and only include the one master legend in the finished map.